# Undefined Variable in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, undefined-variable

I'm new to Laravel and I'm very struggling with it. Please help me. I want to retrieve data from database to display on web page. But It alert message:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined variable

**display.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($displays as $display)
     {{ $display->first_name }}
     {{ $display->last_name }}
@endforeach
```

**DisplayController.php**

```
public function index(){                                              
    $displays = Info::where('id', 1)->get();    
    return view('display', compact("display"));
}
```

Comment: You miss `s` in display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo in your displaycontroller.php

```
return view('display', compact("display"));
```

## should be

```
return view('display', compact("displays"));
```

you are missing the s behind display

Comment: or `@foreach ($displays as $display)` should be `@foreach ($display as $display)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already added 's' to 'display' but it still alerts the same message: "ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable"

Comment: try to `dd($displays);` in your controller to see if it has data. if it has there, try it in your blade. looks like it may be empty. make sure you have a check for that in your blade

Comment: also, ` $displays = Info::where('id', 1)->get();` could be replaced with `$displays = Info::find(1);` [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) makes in smaller and better looking

Comment: @devpro That would still break as $display is not set. Also you should not use the same variable twice in a foreach really, it can get confusing and will probably break.